# How to import .pem file to an AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, pysftp

I am trying to connect to STFP using AWS Lambda which needs a private key file. I am able to connect from local and now I need to deploy it into a Lambda function. But `pysftp.connection` needs `filepath` rather than `keystring` to connect.

Can I package the private file into my Lambda package using YAML file?

```
import pysftp

ftp = pysftp.Connection(host = hostname , username=user, port=22, private_key='...pem')
```

Can I store the pem file in AWS SSM and access file while connection to STFP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't store the file in s3 as the other answer states, this is not good security practice.

Here is a document with an example of how to use SSM secrets with Lambda, I've used this before successfully.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/sharing-secrets-with-aws-lambda-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/

Comment: Can't agree with the blanket "not good security practise" regarding S3. Horses for courses: properly locked down, S3 is fine. That said, SSM or at least SecureString in the Parameter Store is likely a better way, I agree with that.

Comment: My reasoning is that you're still storing passwords that aren't encrypted at rest, which is not good. It's also likely that more than one person is going to have access to your AWS account, and with all the S3 mistakes people make and open up buckets inadvertently - it's not a good place to store passwords. "Not good security practice" is maybe too strong a phrase though.

Comment: I understand - however I come from a "thou shalt never have an S3 bucket without KMS" approach. Ever.

Comment: i need to give path to file in connection parameters and i can't use ssm as it store string values. Is there a way to load a file to ssm and give its path ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could package the `.pem` file as part of your AWS Lambda function code deployment. This would make it available on the local filesystem.

See: [AWS Lambda Deployment Package in Python - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)

Alternatively, you could store the `.pem` file in Amazon S3 and have the AWS Lambda function download it to the `/tmp` directory before use.

Comment: is there any example i can refer to use a extra file in zip file and access in lambda ?

Comment: You can either package it with the zip file (see the above link), but it also looks like you can create an additional file in the Lambda Console, in the editor where you write the Lambda code. Just create a New file and save it with a name. A .pem file is just text, so you can paste the contents into the file.

Comment: Thank you all. I was able to connect to sftp from lambda by storing the key data in ssm parameters and created a tmp file during lambda execution for private key and delete it after completion.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have packaged .pem file and deployed, but when trying to ssh from lambda to ec2 instance (with paramiko), I'm getting "Errno 13 permission error" on the file. How would I fix that?

Comment: @Anil You'll need to debug it to figure it out. You could start by running the code on your local computer to try and reproduce the error. It might be due to the username or PEM file. Feel free to ask another question if you have difficulties.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Are you refering to Brooke ? As i already fixed my code based on your idea. Thank you

Comment: Oops! Yes, my comment was for Brooke.

Answer (score 0):

If you need instructions on creating a deployment package you can check out the video below. Instead of using pip to install a package, you can simply replace copy your .pem file in the lambda_function folder. Then follow the rest of the steps.

https://geektopia.tech/post.php?blogpost=Create_Lambda_Package_Python